# Multiple testfiles and MockRestServiceServer, expecting calls from other testfile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4, resttemplate, mockrestserviceserver

I've build a service with two endpoints, and I want to cover both endpoints with integration tests. To prevent these integrationtests from reaching other services, I'm using the `MockRestServiceServer` class to mock calls and responses to other HTTP services.

TestOperationA:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({"integration"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "nl.xyz")
public class OperationAIntegrationTest {

    MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    OperationA operationA;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).bufferContent().ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
        this.mockServer.reset();
    }

    @After
    public void finish() {
        // Verify all method calls are run after the testcase.
        this.mockServer.verify();
        this.mockServer.reset();
    }
```

And then testcases contain stuff like:

```
this.mockServer.expect(requestTo(ENDPOINT_OAUTH))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oAuthToken), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

I do the same for OperationBIntegrationTest. This includes the binding to `restTemplate`!

Now the problem is that if I run all testcases seperately, everything succeeds. If I run all the testcases from OperationA ór OperationB, they all succeed. But when I run all the testcases so the integrationtests from OperationA and OperationB are executed in sequence, the testcases from OperationB fail. Even though I see that Spring Boot gets started anew when the testing framework jumps to the second testing file.

I'm thinking that the `MockRestServiceServer` does not get cleaned up or I'm doing something wrong with the binding to `RestTemplate`. I tried the `.reset()` and `.verify()` combinations by placing them in `@Before` and `@After`, but with no effect. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, some stuff was happening in the background causing certain variables and methods not being updated anymore since a previous test already updated it. When I don't dirty the application context (by having more MockBean's for example) then everything is allright.

So the ones adjusting the values in the background should be marked dirty.